# how to capitalize first character of sub array keys

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-3.0, capitalization, sub-array

```
Array
(
[Carriers] => Array
    (
        [Carrier] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [carriersid] => a2e01423-2e8f-4458-8c13-2bfd08591d75
                        [phonenumber] => 1234567890
                        [network] => CELLCO PARTNERSHIP DBA VERIZON WIRELESS - CA
                        [wireless] => True
                        [zipcode] => 92675
                        [city] => Capistrano Valley
                        [price] => 3.0000
                        [createddate] => 2016-02-19 06:18:56
                    )
```

I want to capitalize [carriersid] to Carriersid.
I know array_change_key_case function is there but it only make keys either UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE.
Anyhelp is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the possible solution also if you want like this CarrieSid then use following otherwise use the code posted by Rahul -

```
$carrier_arr = $arr['Carriers']['Carrier'];

$final_arr = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($carrier_arr);$i++){

$final_arr[$i]['Carriersid'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['carriersid'];
$final_arr[$i]['Phonenumber'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['phonenumber'];
$final_arr[$i]['Network'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['network'];
$final_arr[$i]['Wireless'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['wireless'];
$final_arr[$i]['Zipcode'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['zipcode'];
$final_arr[$i]['City'] =  $arr[$i]['city'];
$final_arr[$i]['Price'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['price'];
$final_arr[$i]['Createddate'] =  $carrier_arr[$i]['createddate'];

}
```

Comment: One small change is needed in your code for counting array length
for($i=0;$i<count($resultCarrierArr['Carriers']['Carrier']);$i++)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one it will make a first letter capital

```
<?php
    $arr = ['asd'=> '123', 'sdf' => '444'];
    $data = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
       $data[ucfirst($key)] = $val;
    }
    print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This help you to change key of an array first letter capital

```
<?php    
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) {
        $val = ucfirst($val);
    }
    ?>
```